# how to create a calculating property

Tags: c#

say i have a some properties

```
public int redBalls { get; set; }
public int blueBalls { get; set; }
```

I now want to have a totalBalls property which will add the two.

Would I do this?

```
public int totalBalls { get { return redBalls + blueBalls; } }
```

I'm trying this but the result is 0

*edit, i've spoken to my lead developer and it's because whatever accesses totalBalls isn't notified of the changes of redBalls or blueBalls so it wont recalculate those values

So I have to do `OnPropertyChanged("total")`

Comment: Have you actually set `redBalls` and `blueBalls`?

Comment: All is fine, looks like both red/blue balls are 0

Comment: `redBalls` and `blueBalls` are both not zero and not inverses of each other, right?

Comment: @sll They would be 0, not null. They are not a nullable type.

Comment: yes, redBalls and blueBalls are set first, and then I try to access blueBalls, redBalls and totalBalls

Comment: @Aaron McIver : sorry I mean 0

Comment: Can you show us a small complete sample code that has this problem?

Comment: i have edited my post, because I think that's the problem.

Answer (score 1):

Wrote a test for you... This succeeds for me.

```
[Test]
public void SO()
{
    var testing = new Testing();
    Assert.AreEqual(0, testing.RedBalls);
    Assert.AreEqual(0, testing.BlueBalls);
    Assert.AreEqual(0, testing.TotalBalls);

    testing.RedBalls = 2;
    testing.BlueBalls = 4;
    Assert.AreEqual(2, testing.RedBalls);
    Assert.AreEqual(4, testing.BlueBalls);
    Assert.AreEqual(6, testing.TotalBalls);
}

class Testing
{
    public int RedBalls { get; set; }
    public int BlueBalls { get; set; }
    public int TotalBalls { get { return RedBalls + BlueBalls; } }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There is nothing wrong with your code except the capitalisation of the Property names, which is purely cosmetic.

`totalBalls` will = 0 whilst the sum of `redBalls` and `blueBalls` is 0, obviously, they will both = 0 until they are set to some other value.

**EDIT**

You didn't mention `DependecyProperty`s in the OP or the tags, if a dependecy property is bound to the `totalBalls` property it won't know that `totalBalls` is calculated from other properties.

You should extend the definition of your dependency property so that its metadata includes a PropertyChangedCallback that can detect the aggregated changes, rather than coupling your simple class to WPF.

Comment: I would argue there is no need for a **Total** property depending on the usage.

Comment: @Ramhound -agreed. Unless there was reason to make red/blue balls private and provide a total, it is currently bloat.

Comment: don't worry about bloat, it's just a scenario i'm giving you to describe the problem without pasting too much unrelated code.

Answer (score 0):

You must acutally set the value of redBalls/blueBalls

```
class Balls
{
    public int redBalls { get; set; }
    public int blueBalls{ get; set; }

    public int totalBalls{ get{ return redBalls + blueBalls; } }
}

void test()
{
    // You must acutally set the value of redBalls/blueBalls
    var balls = new Balls{ redBalls = 1, blueBalls = 2 };
    Assert.AreEqual(3, balls.totalBalls);
}
```